# magento 1.9 rest api return 404

Tags: magento-1.9

my url pattern http://10.0.20.149/mindcomtest1/index.php/api/rest/products?page=1

I am trying to get the product details by hitting this url but getting 404 error any help would be appreciable ??

Comment: For all API or only for products?

Answer (score 4):

As your question is not very precise, shows no effort that you have  tried to make it work and we know nothing about your configuration one can only guess:

Could be that you are missing a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file

> RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

Did you enable that call for Guest user via system configuration? Otherwise you have to do oauth before!

Comment: Still i am getting same error,  is possible using rest api without oAuth? @ Michael Leiss

Comment: Hello, i have all details:  Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Token Key, Token Secret still not working, i am using REST API in  POSTMAN, return 404 Not Found 1 error, can you pls help me? workout : abc.com/api/rest/products?limit=2  @
Michael Leiss

Comment: For nginx, add this in the vhost file: `location /api { rewrite ^/api/rest /api.php?type=rest last; }`